# What does "get this way" mean?

Tags: meaning

Could you tell me what *get this way* mean? For example:

> You lost your job, started smoking, become overweight. How did you **get this way**?

Is it used to ask what happened to someone?

Comment: Yes, in your context, ***get this way = become like this***. In casual conversational contexts, native speakers use ***get*** a lot more than you'd find in written texts, and *I did it **this way*** is just an equally-valid alternative to *I did it **like this***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb **'get'** (copulative) means *'to become'*.
e.g., He got angry. Don't get drunk tonight.

**"This way"** means *'thus'* or *'like this'*.

> *"How did you get this way?"* = *"How did you become like this?"*